# how to add transtion time on image on hover in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation

I'm working on a react application. I'm stuck on image animation. When the mouse is hover the image it scale to 1.2 times original, but it should be come with transition time of 2s.i I'm able to scale the image but how should I add transition time on. My code:

```
<Image
        src={this.props.data.profile_photo}
        alt={this.props.data.name}
        size="massive"
        avatar
        onClick={this.handleOpen}
        onMouseOut={() => this.setState({hovered: false})}
        onMouseOver={() => this.setState({hovered: true})}
        style={{transform: `${this.state.hovered ? 'scale(1.2,1.2)' : 'scale(1,1)'}`}}
```

I don't know where to put transition thing.

Comment: Have you think on using react animation https://reactjs.org/docs/animation.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried a using a transition yet?

Sorry normally would have put this in a comment, but I'm not points rich yet.

```
style={{transform: `${this.state.hovered ? 'scale(1.2,1.2)' : 'scale(1,1)'}`, transition: `${this.state.hovered ? '0.5s' :  '0.5s;`}}
```

You will likely need to adjust it a bit, but this would work on a standard css styled element.

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transition/

Comment: Or possibly even just  
", transition: '0.2s'}}"

Comment: have you try to work with css transition on reactjs without react.animation?

Comment: You should be able to use it without react.animation as its part of CSS. https://codepen.io/bjornholdt/pen/zZyEga for instance which comes form this wonderful article on medium about exactly this. https://medium.com/@bjorn.holdt/react-animations-101-css-transitions-9c1050c2bc9d all you are doing in by doing this in style is attaching the CSS via React vs the standard DOM element.

Comment: If you modify the transition in the css on that codepen you can see the speeds changing. You are effectively doing that same thing by adding it to style.

Answer (score 0):

[React animation](https://reactjs.org/docs/animation.html)
Quick exmaple this should work:

```
import ReactCSSTransitionGroup from 'react-addons-css-transition-group';
 <ReactCSSTransitionGroup
     transitionName="example"
     transitionAppear={false}
     transitionAppearTimeout={500}
     transitionEnter={true}
     transitionLeave={false}>
   <Image
    src={this.props.data.profile_photo}
    alt={this.props.data.name}
    size="massive"
    avatar
    onClick={this.handleOpen}
    onMouseOut={() => this.setState({hovered: false})}
    onMouseOver={() => this.setState({hovered: true})}
    style={{transform: `${this.state.hovered ? 'scale(1.2,1.2)' : 'scale(1,1)'}`}}
```

css code

```
.example-enter {
  opacity: 0.01;
  }

.example-enter.example-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 500ms ease-in;
 }

 .example-leave {
   opacity: 1;
  }

  .example-leave.example-leave-active {
     opacity: 0.01;
     transition: opacity 300ms ease-in;
  }
```